# FontAwesome Shortcode isn't working properly

Tags: shortcode

```
 function addscFontAwesome($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'type'  => '',
    'size' => '',
    'rotate' => '',
    'flip' => '',
    'pull' => '',
    'animated' => '',
    'class' => '',

    ), $atts));

    $classes  = ($type) ? 'fa-'.$type. '' : 'fa-star';
    $classes .= ($size) ? ' fa-'.$size.'' : '';
    $classes .= ($rotate) ? ' fa-rotate-'.$rotate.'' : '';
    $classes .= ($flip) ? ' fa-flip-'.$flip.'' : '';
    $classes .= ($pull) ? ' pull-'.$pull.'' : '';
    $classes .= ($animated) ? ' fa-spin' : '';
    $classes .= ($class) ? ' '.$class : '';

    $theAwesomeFont = '<i class="fa '.esc_html($classes).'"></i>';

    return $theAwesomeFont;
}

add_shortcode('icon', 'addscFontAwesome');
```

//usage  [icon type="facebook"]

The problem is whatever I insert in the icon type, it always shows star (and that's because in the class attribute there's "fa-star" in it), after removing the "fa-star" I have tried dozen of modification/alternation so that my inserted icon type would show but it doesn't work. I guess I am not seeing it straight, Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** I'm working on a localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code, and it worked for me. Is it possible that your server doesn't support the `extract` function? Using extract is frowned upon in PHP now. This is the recommended way of extracting shortcode attributes:

```
function addscFontAwesome($atts) {

    $args = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'type'  => '',
            'size' => '',
            'rotate' => '',
            'flip' => '',
            'pull' => '',
            'animated' => '',
            'class' => '',
        ),
        $atts,
        'icon'
    );

    $classes  = ($args['type']) ? 'fa-'.$args['type']. '' : 'fa-star';
    $classes .= ($args['size']) ? ' fa-'.$args['size'].'' : '';
    $classes .= ($args['rotate']) ? ' fa-rotate-'.$args['rotate'].'' : '';
    $classes .= ($args['flip']) ? ' fa-flip-'.$args['flip'].'' : '';
    $classes .= ($args['pull']) ? ' pull-'.$args['pull'].'' : '';
    $classes .= ($args['animated']) ? ' fa-spin' : '';
    $classes .= ($args['class']) ? ' '.$args['class'] : '';

    $theAwesomeFont = '<i class="fa '.esc_attr($classes).'"></i>';

    return $theAwesomeFont;
}
add_shortcode('icon', 'addscFontAwesome');
```

Make sure you're using the latest version of Font Awesome. Here's the code I'm using:

```
function nateallen-font-awesome() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'nateallen-font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.4.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nateallen-font-awesome' );
```

Comment: +1 for not using extract ;-) I would tend to use `esc_attr` to escape the class *attribute*, instead of `esc_html`, even though they're almost the same. I would also add the third parameter of `shortcode_atts`. Also use prefixed shortcode name. But these are just my personal opinions ;-)

Comment: @birgire Good suggestions, thank you. I edited the code to include `esc_attr` and the `$shortcode` parameter. I left the shortcode name the same though, but he can change that if he wants (it is very generic and could conflict with another shortcode easily).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I am working on a localhost. btw [icon type="facebook"] [icon type="car"] or even [icon type="calendar"] works I mean displays FA icons but [icon type="map"] [icon type="opera"] [icon type="hourglass"] these doesn't work. I was hoping I could get all the FA icons through this shortcode. Is there any particular reasons for not working!

Comment: So when you do `[icon type="facebook"]` it works, but `[icon type="map"]` doesn't? When you view the source code, what does it show when it doesn't work?

Comment: In Page Source it's showing <i class="fa fa-opera"></i> which is correct syntax for viewing FA icon. No error on the console either. Does Opera, Hourglass and map Icon display on your end?  I guess something have to do with my end.

Comment: So that means there isn't anything wrong with the code. I would check to make sure the Font Awesome CSS is correct.

Comment: I know what's wrong... you're using an older version of Font Awesome. The ones that are working for you are older icons, and the ones that aren't working are new icons. I updated my answer to show the version that I'm using.

Comment: I already downloaded the latest version and enqueued it and it's working. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.